# Touchard / van der Pol's identity for the sum of divisors and an elliptic curve for perfect numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

In [Touchard (1953)](https://oeis.org/A000385/a000385.pdf) it is mentioned that the sum of divisors $\sigma(n)$, satisifies the following recurrence relation ($n>1$):

$$n^2(n-1) = \frac{6}{\sigma(n)} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(3n^2-10k^2)\sigma(k)\sigma(n-k)$$

Substituting in this equation a perfect number $n = \sigma(n)/2$ we find that $P=(n:n^2:1)$ is a point of the elliptic curve:

$$E_n: y^2=x^3+x^2 a_n -b_n$$

where

$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 9 \sigma(k) \sigma(n-k)$$
and
$$b_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 30k^2 \sigma(k) \sigma(n-k)$$

This elliptic curve can be defined for every $n>1$.

Computations with [SAGEMATH](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyVjkFrwzAMhe_5FaInOagh7QajhZ2G77mXMZzGDSatbBS7dP9-cRo22HqZdJH0eN9TZ09gDLLaFzCV2JiEYUwXPOzK0fUXg4NaBl4PCk5eYADHIIZ7ixti9a6Kops4bfuQ81SXQ1lu_0vT-jdNn88uRHd8S3K1eKhpfpzqqddzdrZmIv8Qt_S8e1kwGl7v1HmL8nk_52qyVAXvOCIy8fQvbZT61oNkhamhpvLSWUFFuopeRuf5Y0xtLz4FXBz2drQh7v-4V-wjGJhjVo_9Xzn3cuA=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) suggest, that the torsion subgroup of this elliptic curve is trivial (for all natural numbers $n$), and that the order of the point $P$ is $+\infty$ ( conjecture: $P$ is a point of $E_n$, if and only if $n$ is perfect).

1. Question: Can this be proven?
2. Question: Does this curve have any interesting properties?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your assertions are for any n or just for perfect n's?

Comment: @Xarles:  The curve can be defined for any $n>1$ and seem to always have trivial torsion group. $P$ seems to be a point of $E_n$ if and only if $n$ is a perfect number. In this case $P$ seems to have infinite order.

Comment: Torsion is trivial for most elliptic curves; probably with a bit of hard work one could determine for which $n$, if any, it isn't trivial. The denominator of $2P$ is even it seems, that would show that it is of infinite order. Unless I am mistaken $P$ is on $E_n$ if and only if $n$ is perfect by the initial formula (and it will not have anything to do with $E_n$). The curve $E_n$ has positive rank for many other $n$. So, I am not sure where this is heading.