# Why can one compute the sum of divisors of $n$ without factoring $n$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, intuition, integer-sequences, oeis

[Question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372258/touchard-van-der-pols-identity-for-the-sum-of-divisors-and-an-elliptic-curve) links to [paper](https://oeis.org/A000385/a000385.pdf)
which states:
$$
\sigma(n)= \frac{6}{n^2(n-1)}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(3n^2-10k^2)\sigma(k)\sigma(n-k) \qquad (1)
$$

where $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of divisors of $n$.

Another similar result from [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000010)
about Euler totient function:
$$
\phi(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n |k(n,i)| \qquad (2)
$$

where $k(n,i)$ is the Kronecker symbol.

And

$$
\phi(n) = \operatorname{binomial}(n+1, 2) - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \phi(i)\lfloor n/i\rfloor \qquad (3)
$$

Observe that the RHS of all of the above doesn't require the
factorization of $n$ and in addition (2) doesn't require factorization
at all.

We find the (1) and (3) factorization of $n$-free identities counter-intuitive.

> Q1 Is there any intuition why such identities exist?

> Q2 Are there similar factorization of $n$-free identities
> for $\omega(n)$ or $\Omega(n)$ (the number of prime factors of $n$)
> (not counting the generating function)?

Comment: You might introduce the post in a way that makes it more understandable without clicking the links. Also the question in the title is not repeated in the post, but it probably should be somewhere.

Comment: There is no reason why identities about $\sigma(n)$ should involve factorization. To begin with, the very *definition* of $\sigma(n)$ is an identity without factorization. The same goes for $\phi(n)$, but additionally note that the expression in (2) is quite silly: $|k(n,i)|$ is just a funny way of writing the indicator function of coprimality, hence (2) is just an obfuscation of the defining formula $\phi(n)=|\{i\le n:\gcd(n,i)=1\}|$.

Comment: I think the surprising fact is that formula (1) does not involve divisors of $n$. The definition of $\sigma(n)$ does not involve the factorization of $n$, but divisors of $n$.

Comment: There is also Euler's recurrence $$\sigma(n)=\sigma(n-1)+\sigma(n-2)-\sigma(n-5)-\sigma(n-7)+\sigma(n-12)+\sigma(n-15)-\cdots$$ where $1,2,5,7,12,15,\dots$ are the pentagonal numbers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: you are confusing $\sigma(n)$ with $p(n)$, the number of partitions of $n$. Perhaps you are thinking of $np(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma(i)p(n-i)$.

Comment: Gerry's comment seems correct; see, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/a/22744

Comment: Gerry's comment is almost correct, but you need to set $\sigma(0)=n$ when $n$ is a pentagonal number.